# how to include copyright notice and this permission notice inside tha android app

Tags: android, open-source, licensing

I have modified some one's app with MIT license and i have put my ad code to make revenue from it. in the MIT license it is said **"The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."**
where do i put this in the android app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific place where to put that in application. I used to put in settings/profile under item **Open source license**. Take a look on app **Google play**.

**Update 2/4/2016:**

MIT License mentioned this clearly ( [source](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_MIT) ) :

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

You can argue that software here is a SourceCode .. but morally and customarily software is app. so I would go with that you should credit the author somewhere in your app. not in a hidden place like in res as inaccessible publicly.

Comment: whether it means that i have to show the license to users. can i add it the location like app/res/

Comment: is it okay to have a webview for the license? what's your app name.

Comment: Yes, Also there are many open sources achieving that: https://github.com/PSDev/LicensesDialog also https://github.com/adamsp/AndroidLicensesPage or https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries